# Javascript Promise resolve method prints in console. How?

Tags: promise, es6-promise

Please have a look at the below javascript code. When I run this code in browser console window the below mentioned output is received. I am new to javascript and promises. Please help me understand how "resolved" got printed in browser console?

```
    function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
     
    async function asyncCall() {
      console.log('calling');
      const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
      console.log(result);
    }
    asyncCall();
```

OUTPUT in browser console:

calling

**resolved**

Now my question is why "resolved" got printed in console? As of what I know is then() method should have executed when resolve() method is called.

Comment: Because that's what `console.log(result);` does? What exactly is unexpected about this?

Comment: @Bergi what I was not able to understand is how `result` got the value `resolved` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await` operator is used to wait for the `Promise` to settle. It returns the fulfilled value of the `Promise` or the value itself if its not a `Promise`.

In your code, since `resolveAfter2Seconds()` function returns a `Promise`, so in the following statement

```
const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
```

javascript waits for the `Promise` to settle and then assigns its fulfillment value, i.e. `'resolved'` to the `result` constant. After that, you log the `result` on the console which is why `'resolved'` gets logged on the console.

Comments above each statement in the `asyncCall` function will help you understand the output.

```
async function asyncCall() {
  // log 'calling' on the console
  console.log('calling');   

  // wait for the promise to resolve and then
  // assign the fulfillment value to 'result'                   
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds(); 

  // log the value with which promise returned
  // by 'resolveAfter2Seconds' function resolved
  console.log(result);                         
}
```

> As of what I know is then() method should have executed when resolve()
> method is called.

I can't see where you have called `.then()` method in your code. `.then()` method is invoked if you register any callback calling `.then()` method on any `Promise`.

Instead of using `async-await` syntax, you could change your code as shown below to see that callback registered using `.then()` is invoked after 2 seconds.

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// store the promise returned by 'resolveAfter2Seconds' function
const p = resolveAfter2Seconds();

// register a callback function to be invoked after 2
// seconds with the resolved value
p.then(resolvedValue => {
  console.log('callback invoked');
  console.log('Promise resolved with the value of: ' + resolvedValue);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Its clear from your question that you are confused about the output of the code because it uses `async-await` syntax instead of `promise-chaining`. `async-await` is syntactic sugar over the regular promise code that uses `.then()` method calls.

I suggest that you visit the following links to understand how `async-await` syntax works. Once you understand that, you will be able to understand the output.

- [`MDN - await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [`MDN - async functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: but `result` should store Promise instance because that is what resolveAfter2Seconds() method is doing and the then() method should receive the value given by resolve() method.

Comment: `calling` string value and promise object got logged twice in console after removing await keyword:
`calling`


`Promise {<pending>}`


`Promise {<fulfilled>}`

Comment: If you remove the `await` keyword, code you have posted in your question will only log `calling` and `Promise {<pending>}`.

Comment: I completely understands the code that you have posted without await and async. Thats how it given in the tutorial article on google. But I am not able to understand the output when I am not providing any then() method.

Comment: @Garvit `await` "unpacks" the promise. It waits for the promise to finish and returns the wrapped result.

Comment: @QBrute your comment popped up one more question in my mind that what if `rejected` is called instead of `resolved`. I ran the script and "resolved" was not logged , only "calling" was logged.

Comment: If you wrap the code in the async function with the `try-catch` block, if promise is rejected, `catch` block will be invoked. You can also chain a `catch` method in the calling code to handle the promise rejection.